# Korean CSAT killer problem

Tags: functions

A function ${\displaystyle f(x)})$ defined for ${\displaystyle x>a}$, where ${\displaystyle a}$ is a constant, and a quartic function ${\displaystyle g(x)}$ whose leading coefficient is ${\displaystyle -1}$ satisfy the three conditions below:

A) For all real numbers ${\displaystyle x}$, such that ${\displaystyle x>a}$, ${\displaystyle (x-a)f(x)=g(x)}$

B) For two different real numbers ${\displaystyle \alpha }$  and ${\displaystyle \beta }$ , ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ has the same local maximum ${\displaystyle M}$ at ${\displaystyle x=\alpha }$  and ${\displaystyle x=\beta }$ . $({\displaystyle M>0}$

C) ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ has more local extrema than ${\displaystyle g(x)}$ does.
${\displaystyle \beta -\alpha =6{\sqrt {3}}}$. Find the minimum of ${\displaystyle M}$

My solution is as follow

$x-a>0$ and $(x-a)f(x)=g(x)$

Hence $f(x)=-x^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Given $f'(\alpha)=0$ and $f'(\beta)=0$ and $f''(\alpha)<0$ and $f''(\beta)<0$ and also $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$

How do we proceed from here. For reference the I got the question from the following website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_Scholastic_Ability_Test#Mathematics_2

Comment: You should also use the information $f$ has more local extrema than $g$ somewhere. $f$ has exactly 3 (cubic with two distinct local maxima), hence $g$ has at most 2, a generic quartic has 4.

Comment: @quarague This is korean CASAT problem , if $f(x) has three toots then definitely one is local maxima and the other is local minima but how can we have have two distinct local maxima, this is the main problem

Comment: You are right, I miscounted the extrema. f is a cubic, so if it is defined on the entire real line it has at most two local extrema, a min and a max. The only way I see two local max is if one of them is at a. This would be a local max if f is defined for $x \ge a$. The text says f is only defined for $x >a$, which makes this very strange. If you go with one max at $x=a$ one can write out a few equations but it becomes a big mess, not sure whether that is intended.

Comment: That is why it is called killer problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polynomial function with restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4426980/polynomial-function-with-restrictions)